# eclipse java how to had sqlite-jdbc-(VERSION).jar into my project and use it

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

my scenario : on my work on android sqlite i noticed I need to build the sql data base outside the app in java

therfor as one who knows nothing about how to install ***.jar files i google it 
all the example for how to install it weren't relevant for my situation where my platform is eclipse in windows 7 .

i would someone to instract me how to do the fallowing

- i have downloaded  sqlitejdbc-v056 and now i wish to append it to my project
- how can I open a new data base , can i do :

  ```
   Class.forName("sqlitejdbc-v056");
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/STERN/workspace/Test1/src/notexistyet.db");
  ```

  where notexistyet doesnt exist and by writing the last it will b created

thank u.

Comment: What is "Internet OS explaining"?
´

Comment: I will refrain from answering this only because the question is so poorly stated. Please at least make an effort when you want people to help you.

Comment: Nubsis I wish I explained myself well this time as you can guess I am no English native speaker and sometimes i find it hard to explain myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i understand, you need to add sqlitejdbc-v056.jar to your Libraries (build path) so that you can use the jar file.

Right click on your `Eclipse Project->Build Path->Configure Build Path...->Add External Jar` (under libraries)

Browse to the JAR file and add it.

Then this will work:

```
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
```

[Source](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/)